# Is it safe to delete the user account in Documents&Settings if the user has been disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, user-accounts

Having disabled User Account Fred with the command lusrmgr.msc, is it now safe to delete the user folder Fred from Documents and Settings?

Can Fred be removed from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList?

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer need that user, you can delete it from User Accounts (Sorry, I don't recall the appropriate location in XP right now). If you are asked to also delete files, answer yes (assuming you have done your backup and there is nothing more you want to keep).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete the folder until the account is **deleted**. Disabled accounts can be enabled and used again.

Comment: OK. I've deleted Fred but he still appears in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList. Delete that too?

Answer (score -1):

disable user:

```
net user Fred /active:no
```

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList

only hide user account at logon GIU screen.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.